# How do I evaulate this iterated integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I changed the limits of integration and then simply integrated, but I keep getting the same wrong answer?
Am I doing it incorrectly?
My answer was, rounded: 3.808

[image: integral]

Comment: What are your bounds of integration after switching the order?

Comment: From 0 to 4 (very left integral paired up with dy) and from 0 to y/4 (paired with dx)

Comment: Ok, I agree these bounds are correct, so something must be going wrong in between the setup and the answer

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. First integrate x and keep y as a constant. Then use u-substitution to integrate the leftover y function.

Comment: That is the correct method, but the answer I get is $\frac{1}{144}\left[67^{3/2}-3^{3/2}\right]\approx3.77$?

Comment: Ahh I see thank you. I made a mistake and assumed the latter would be 0